# Four points A, B, C and D lie on a circle, respectively, knowing that AB = CD, prove that ABCD is an isosceles trapezoid.

Tags: geometry, circles, quadrilateral

I try to prove ABCD is a trapezoid buy prove AD//BC but have no idea.
Let I be the intersection of AB and CD. I try using thales theorem but still can't.
[image]

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please read this text about [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Answer (score 0):

$\angle CBD = \angle BCA$($\angle$ 's are subtended $=$ segments)

$\angle ABD = \angle DCA$($\angle$ 's are subtended same segments)

Hence $\angle B = \angle C$

$\angle A = 180^o - \angle C$ (opp. $\angle$ 's are supp.)

$AD \parallel BC,(\angle A + \angle B=180^o$, co-interior $\angle$ 's)